# CGAL - Proper way of adding data to Triangle class

Tags: c++, cgal

I have begun using CGAL and encountered an issue I am not able to solve. I load a model as a list of triangles and want to store additional information for each triangle - a color. I also want to use the AABB tree from CGAL but I have noticed that I have basically two options:

```
class DataTriangle {
public:
     Point_3 x;
     Point_3 y;
     Point_3 z;

     int color;         
}
```

1. Follow the "AABB_custom_example.cpp" example and create a functor that converts my DataTriangle to a CGAL::Simple_cartesian::Triangle_3 every time. This wastes computation time because it constructs new Triangle_3 object every time.
2. I can make my own triangle and include Triangle_3 as a member:

   ```
   class MyTriangle {
       Triangle mTriangleCgal;
       int color;
       const Triangle& getTri() const { return mTriangleCgal; }
   }
   ```

   Then again declare a My_triangle_primitive functor, define

   ```
   typedef K::Point_3    Point;
   typedef K::Triangle_3 Datum;
   typedef const K::Triangle_3& Datum_reference;
   ```

   and reference the underlying triangle as such.

   ```
   Datum_reference datum() { return tri->getTri(); }
   ```

   Is this solution okay? I feel it should not waste time by constructing any new objects. Am I right?
3. The third idea I came up with is simply creating a custom iterator that will go through the vector of MyTriangles and instead of the class itself, return the Triangle_3 class. I should be able to pass this iterator into the AABB tree constructor and get the tree constructed from plain Triangle_3 objects, which should work just fine.

Is there another way of approach that I missed that is prefered to these three? Is number 2 okay to use if there is not another way?

Thank you

Comment: Seems you over-engineer there. If you need Triangle_3 then store it. If you need color then store it, if you need both then store both. If you do so then don't store Point_3 since Triangle_3::operator[] already returns those points of it.

Comment: Yes, my primary concern is how I should feed the stored Triangle_3 into the AABB. If I store both color and Triangle_3 in a class MyTriangle, as you say, I can't feed a vector of MyTriangle into the AABB because it is not a Primitive. (the first example is basically just an overview of what I want to achieve, not the actual implementation)

Comment: You can keep two synchronized vectors: one of Triangle_3 and other of color.

Comment: @ÖöTiib solution is good but you can also use your struct or a std::pair and then use a [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) so as to have an iterator with `value_type` being the triangle type the AABB-tree expects. Since the primitive id is this iterator type, you can get access to your initial iterator by using the `base()` method.

Comment: @sloriot oh, that is an interesting option, I have not used boost much so I didn't know that I can use that and not write my own. Thanks for pointing that out.